# Permission denied for ls in tomcat directory

Tags: permissions

My user belongs to *developer* group as soon as the user called *tomcat*. When I do `ls -la /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.19` it gives me

```
total 160
drwxrwxr-x 11 tomcat developer  4096 mai 14 14:41 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 tomcat developer  4096 mai 13 14:07 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 tomcat developer  4096 mai 14 14:41 backup
drwxrwx---  2 tomcat developer  4096 mai 13 14:03 bin
-rw-rw----  1 tomcat developer 19182 abr 12 11:26 BUILDING.txt
drwxrwx---  3 tomcat developer  4096 mai 14 14:02 conf
-rw-rw----  1 tomcat developer  5407 abr 12 11:26 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxrwx---  2 tomcat developer  4096 mai 13 14:03 lib
-rw-rw----  1 tomcat developer 57092 abr 12 11:26 LICENSE
drwxrwx---  2 tomcat developer  4096 mai 15 10:20 logs
-rw-rw----  1 tomcat developer  2333 abr 12 11:26 NOTICE
-rw-rw----  1 tomcat developer  3255 abr 12 11:26 README.md
-rw-rw----  1 tomcat developer  6852 abr 12 11:26 RELEASE-NOTES
-rw-rw----  1 tomcat developer 16262 abr 12 11:26 RUNNING.txt
drwxrwx---  2 tomcat developer  4096 mai 15 12:10 temp
drwxrwx---  8 tomcat developer  4096 mai 13 15:08 webapps
drwxrwx---  3 tomcat developer  4096 mai 13 14:12 work
drwxrwxr-x  4 tomcat developer  4096 mai 14 14:41 wtpwebapps
```

But when I do `ls -la /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.19/conf` it gives me `permission denied`. Any idea about what is happening?

---

Updade: Additional information:
using `pathlld /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.19/conf/` gives me

```
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096 mai 15 12:30 /
/dev/sda8 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 mai 13 13:58 /opt
drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat developer 4096 mai 13 14:07 /opt/tomcat
drwxrwxr-x 11 tomcat developer 4096 mai 14 14:41 /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.19
drwxrwx--- 3 tomcat developer 4096 mai 14 14:02 /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.19/conf
```

Another estrange behavior is when I do `id rafael` it gives me

```
uid=1000(rafael) gid=1000(rafael) grupos=1000(rafael),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),113(lpadmin),128(sambashare),130(libvirtd),130(libvirtd),1003(developer)
```

but when I do `id` logged as *rafael* it gives me

```
uid=1000(rafael) gid=1000(rafael) grupos=1000(rafael),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),113(lpadmin),128(sambashare),130(libvirtd)
```

that is the same information without the group *developer*

Comment: Please, paste `id your_user` output.

Comment: You could use my `pathlld` script (`sudo pathlld /opt/tomcat/latest/conf`). https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git - Bash script to answer "Why can't I read/write that file?"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys. I shutdown the computer and when I return, I tried it again and everything works as expected. Apparently the system needed to restart to complete some process.